# Nim: read all content of text file

Tags: nim-lang

I liked to read the whole content of a text file using Nim.

I tried

```
let fileContent: string = readAll("file.txt")
```

but this doesn't compile.

Comment: readAll requires a file handle not the file name

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [readAll proc requires as parameter a `File`](https://nim-lang.org/1.6.4/io.html#readAll%2CFile), which is what [open](https://nim-lang.org/1.6.4/io.html#open%2Cstring%2CFileMode%2Cint) returns. However, for a one liner you could use [readFile](https://nim-lang.org/1.6.4/io.html#readFile%2Cstring):

```
let fileContent = readFile("file.txt")
```

Answer (score 2):

It is most easily done so:

```
let filepath: string = "file.txt"
let f = open(filepath, fmRead)
let fileContent: string = readAll(f)
f.close()
```

(nothing has to get imported to do that)